# jquery select2 tag get value out of default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How do I get the value out of the default value, which mean I want to get new value custom insert by user only.

E.g now my default value is "red", "green", "blue".
If user enter "yellow", "black". I just want the **new tag** been notified, so I can store in database for next round pre-populate for next user.

**My select2 version is 3.4.2**

HTML :

```
<input id="tags" class="text-input form-control"  type="text" name="tags" size="24"  placeholder="tags" >
```

JS:(in docs)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tags").select2({
    tags: ["red", "green", "blue"],
    maximumInputLength: 10
    });
});
```

I am using old version of JQuery and old version select2
Fiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/jb4b2cnu/

how do create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem properly which is to **add new tag if it is not present and notify to `database` too** then you can set a variable on **creating newTag** through an option `createTag` and then make use of `select2.select` event to send or notify your `db` about newly added `tag`. For example:

```
$("#tags").select2({
    tags: ["red", "green", "blue"],
    maximumInputLength: 10,
    createTag: function (tag) {
        return {
            id: tag.term,
            text: tag.term,
            isNew : true
        };
    }
}).on("select2:select", function(e) {
    if(e.params.data.isNew){
        alert('make db call here');            
        $(this).find('[value="'+e.params.data.id+'"]').replaceWith('<option selected value="'+e.params.data.id+'">'+e.params.data.text+'</option>');
    }
});
```

A Sample **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jnw96phd/7/)**

Comment: Hi Guruprasad Rao, thank for your solution! As I test your code is running good in select2 4.0. However my development is using version 3.5 version. I had updated with fiddle, can you have a look? Thanks!

Comment: @Shiro.. After searching all the sites I come to conclusion that there is no option to either add new element into list of option, not sure though, or to notify whether the tag is **new** but there is an event called `select2.selecting` instead of `select2:select` but again there isn't much option to manipulate..

Answer (score 1):

After I research on an old version documentation, answer post from ([Select2 with createSearchChoice uses newly created choice for keyboard entry even given a match, bug or am I missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606092/select2-with-createsearchchoice-uses-newly-created-choice-for-keyboard-entry-eve)) and combine Guruprasad Rao idea.

This is what I can archive in an old version.

```
var result = ["red", "green", "blue"];
var isNew = false;
var varNew = [];
i = 0;
$("#tags").select2({
    tags: result,
    maximumInputLength: 10,
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {  
       if(result.some(function(r) { return r.text == term })) {
            return { id: term, text: term };
        }
        else {
            isNew = true;
            varNew[i++] = term;
            return { id: term, text: term + " (new)" };
        } 
     },
});
```